# Is it okay to use the Name of this site in a Clan?

Tags: support, legal

With the chatroom [Summoners Rift](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2348/summoners-rift) being reopened, the small (and growing) amount of users that play League now have a place to hang out and chat etc. We often play together for fun and now we've found around 10 users who play on the European server. This would be enough to build a team with backup in League of Legends that only consists of users of the site. Now the team itself wouldn't be really professional. We have players from all rankings in the chat.

Now my Question: Is it allowed to use the name Gaming Stackexchange as a team name? Of course I'm not talking about LoL only here. Diablo, Counterstrike etc also have clans / teams or guilds. So if we want to play as a team with a name can we use the site name or do we have to use something different?

Comment: There is an Arqade community on steam and two in Diablo 3 (one US and one EU). SO I guess you'd be fine.

Comment: In general, names like **Gaming Stack Exchange Community** or **Arqade Community** are good. Naming the group without the Community suffix is less good, as it could be misinterpreted as an official or formally affiliated group.

Comment: @fredley what about *Gaming Stackexchange EUW*? EUW is basically the LoL server and while it's not as clear as *community* it still doesn't sound extremely official (compared to the name alone). Is it just important to add something in the end or does it have to be absolutely clear that we represent the site in almost no way?

Comment: @Jutschge I have no idea what LoL acronyms mean. Is EUW an acronym? I hope so. If so, what does it mean?

Comment: @fredley Just means Europe West. There are some different LoL servers (EUW, Europe nordic & east, North America etc)

Comment: @Jutschge Since EUW is just a geographic identifier, in my opinion it would still be better to include the Community suffix. All of the steam groups, youtube channels, Minecraft servers etc that are operated by/for the community use this word, and consistency is nice.

Answer (score 1):

The guidance you seek is [here](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

Comment: That page doesn't seem to cover this issue.  It looks to be aimed at someone using the Stack Exchange API to support a site.  Unless you are suggesting that the asker [contact them](mailto:team@stackexchange.com), there's little that seems relevant to this question.  You can sort of see it as suggesting not to use "Stack Exchange" in the name, although even then it's unclear if it's meant to apply in this situation.

Comment: @Brythan it's the guidance we were given when creating the Arqade group on Steam. (It's called "Arqade Community".)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sorry I had to :P